# Combining Fitnesse, .NET and RESTful APIs

Tags: .net, rest, integration-tests

I know there is [Fitsharp](https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp) for combining [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) and .NET. And there is [RestFixture](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture) to combine Fitnesse and REST.

Is there a way to test a RESTful service with Fitnesse under .NET?

If not, is there a different way to perform integration testing on web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was viewing it from the wrong perspective. I can build my webservice with any programming language I like, deploy it on some test server and test it with Fitnesse and RestFixture. No problems.